# How to configure two daemons to use the same database?

Tags: monerod, lmdb, blockchain-data

Do I just have to make sure they have the same data-dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 0.11 (and possibly 0.10.3.1, though I'm not 100% certain this was ready then), there is no particular precautions to take in order to share a database between two daemons. Pointing the daemons to the same directory using `--data-dir` should be safe. I'm not sure this has been tested a lot, however, so if anything like corruption should happen, please report it to https://github.com/monero-project/issues.

Comment: It was possible in 0.10.3.1, but there were weird interactions with the txpool. In 0.11 the txpool is also stored in LMDB so those problems disappear. I've had multiple daemons running with a shared DB for a few months already, no other issues.